# Unix script to analyze the input, depending on the type of character

Tags: unix, input

I am having some time with my script here

1. The script reads the character from the keyboard.
2. Depending on the type of character, the script displays one of the following
   messages

Uppercase letter  Lowercase letter Digit Special character.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'Enter single character:'
read $1
if $1 = "A-Z"
then
  echo 'Uppercase letter'
fi

if $1 = "a-z"
then
  echo 'Lowercase letter'
fi

if $1 = [ ! @ $ ^ & * ~ ? . | / [ ] < > \ ` " ;# ( )]
then
  echo 'Special character'
fi
```

### Though its not working properly.

Here is the short working one:

#!/bin/bash
 echo "Enter single character:"
  read input_source
  case "$input_source" in
       [[:lower:]])  echo "Lowercase letter"
                 ;;
       [[:upper:]])
                 echo "Uppercase letter"
                 ;;
       [0-9]   ) echo "Digit";;
       *       ) echo "Special Character";;
  esac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
usage ()
{
  echo usage: $0 CHAR
  exit
}

[[ $1 ]] || usage

if [[ $1 =~ [[:upper:]] ]]
then
  echo 'uppercase letter'
elif [[ $1 =~ [[:lower:]] ]]
then
  echo 'lowercase letter'
elif [[ $1 =~ [[:punct:]] ]]
then
  echo 'special character'
fi
```

[Regular expression](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Answer (score 2):

I do have some advice for you...

- It's probably best to install ash or dash. These shells correspond to the Posix-standardized shell syntax. Their main advantage to you is: *the man page will be simpler and easier to read.* You can find the man page online as well. It describes the important subset of bash that is Posix.
- There are two ways of evaluating shell conditionals. One is `if ... fi` and the other is `case ... esac`. But the `if` statement *does not evaluate expressions,* it evaluates *pipelines* and *commands*. So, one usually runs the `test` command, which does evaluate expressions, and which is aliased to `[` .

---

```
if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then
  echo success
else
  echo failure
fi

if grep pattern file; then
  echo another success
fi
```

---

- Note that the `[ ... ]` is not *syntax*, it's just short for saying `if test ...; then`.
- The `case ... esac` statement will do pattern matching.